# Android: Comparing current date and time with the date and time in a database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, date

I am currently trying to create an alarm app within android as part of my coursework. Currently everything is working apart from the part which does a date and time check with what's in the database.

Within my "AlarmCheckDateAndTime, I need help with

- Comparing the current date with all dates in into a database
- Comparing the current time with time in the same record as the date

The way I was thinking to do this would be to have two "if" statements within that class file. One which will do the date checking, and within that, the one which time checks. Would there be any chance someone could provide me with some help?

My AlarmCheckDateAndTime class file

```
public class AlarmCheckDateAndTime{
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler;



public static void main (String[] args){
    Date ThisDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    String DateChecker = formatter.format(ThisDate);

    Date ThisTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat timeformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    String TimeChecker = formatter.format(ThisTime);

  }
}
```

My UserInputAlarmData class file

```
    public class UserInputAlarmData {
        private int _id;
        private String _title, _date, _time, _song;


        public UserInputAlarmData (int id, String title, String date, String time, String song){
            _id = id;
            _title = title;
            _date = date;
            _time = time;
            _song = song;

        }

        public String get_title() {
            return _title;
        }

        public String get_date() {
            return _date;
        }

        public String get_time() {
            return _time;
        }

        public String get_song() {
            return _song;
        }

        public int getId() {return  _id;}
        public String getTitle() {return _title;}
        public String getDate() {return _date;}
        public String getTime() {return _time;}
        public String getSong() {return  _song;}
    }
```

My DatabaseHandler class

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FoodTekTrakr",
            DATABASE_TABLE = "AlarmManager",
            KEY_ID = "id",
            KEY_TITLE = "title",
            KEY_DATE = "date",
            KEY_TIME = "time",
            KEY_SONG = "song";


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT," + KEY_TIME + " TEXT," + KEY_SONG + " TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void createAlarm(UserInputAlarmData AlarmData){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_TITLE, AlarmData.getTitle());
        values.put(KEY_DATE, AlarmData.getDate());
        values.put(KEY_TIME, AlarmData.getTime());
        values.put(KEY_SONG, AlarmData.getSong());


        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public UserInputAlarmData getAlarmData(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_DATE, KEY_TIME, KEY_SONG}, KEY_ID
                + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null );

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        UserInputAlarmData AlarmData = new UserInputAlarmData(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4));
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
        return AlarmData;
    }

    public void deleteAlarm(UserInputAlarmData AlarmData){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(AlarmData.getId()) });
        db.close();
    }

    public int getAlarmDataCount() {
        SQLiteDatabase db =getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);

        int count = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        return count;
    }

    public int updateAlarmData(UserInputAlarmData AlarmData){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_TITLE, AlarmData.getTitle());
        values.put(KEY_DATE, AlarmData.getDate());
        values.put(KEY_TIME, AlarmData.getTime());
        values.put(KEY_SONG, AlarmData.getSong());


        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, values, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(AlarmData.getId())});
    }

    public List<UserInputAlarmData> getAllAlarmData() {
        List<UserInputAlarmData> AlarmDatas = new ArrayList<UserInputAlarmData>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                UserInputAlarmData AlarmData = new UserInputAlarmData(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4));
                AlarmDatas.add(AlarmData);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return  AlarmDatas;
    }

}
```

If you need to view any other class files, I can provide them.

Thank you very much in advance for the help

Comment: In what format you are storing the time in the database

Comment: Instead of SimpleDateFormat use Calendar which is fast when compared

Comment: if you store the timestamp it is much easier to compare

Answer (score 0):

Now when you want to insert date to database, you can use this code.

From Date to String.

```
SimpleDateFormat  dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
try {  
  Date date = new Date();  
 String datetime = dateFormat.format(date); // this date & time you can store in database as a string 
 System.out.println("Current Date Time : " + datetime); 
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

In database insert the string 'date'

The date format in sqlite should be of following format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
HH:MM
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.SSS
now
DDDDDDDDDD
```

For more details, have a look to [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

After saving the date as string to the database, you will get the string date if you try to retrieve it back..

So, retrieve a particular string data by using id.. now you have a string type of date. So again convert into date

From String to Date

```
String dtStart = "2010-10-15T09:27:37";  // example this is your string date
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");  
try {  
    Date dbDate = format.parse(dtStart);  // database date in date format
    System.out.println(dbDate);  
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

coming to the date comparison, you can compare both date & time at a time only. So now you have two dates. one is your current system date and another is your data base date. so compare the both by using the below method.

```
 public static Boolean diff( Date date1,
            Date date2 )
    {
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(); // your current date
        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();  // your database date

        c1.setTime( date1 );
        c2.setTime( date2 );


        if( c1.before( c2 ) )
        {
            return true;  // database date is after the current date 
        }
        else if( c2.before( c1 ) )
        {
           return false;  // database date is before the current date 
        }

    }
```

Here Date1 is your current date and Date2 is your database date.

By passing this two dates to the above method  you will get a Boolean value of true/false it will tell whether there is any difference between current date and database date.

If you want to check all the date's in the data base means, you can get the List of UserInputAlarmData from your data base by using this.

```
public List<UserInputAlarmData> getAllAlarmData() {
        List<UserInputAlarmData> AlarmDatas = new ArrayList<UserInputAlarmData>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                UserInputAlarmData AlarmData = new UserInputAlarmData(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4));
                AlarmDatas.add(AlarmData);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return  AlarmDatas;
    }
```

After getting List you can make a loop and check the date's one by one based on your list size.

Hope it will helps you

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. However, that's not quite what I needed. What I need to do is retrieve the database date

Comment: for saving date in db,  convert your date to string and store the string value in database. after retrieving that string date again convert to date.. In this way you can achieve it easily. If you feel any complexity i am ready to explain in a formal way @Goldinegg

Comment: How would I retrieve the database date from the database?

Comment: in the above way you can achieve your task @Goldinegg

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you store your dates.

You can either use

1. Use the calendar format.

   ```
   Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
   cal.setTimeInMillis(getYourMillisFromTheDBInHere);
   ```

   // Now you can compare the fields

   ```
   cal.get(Calendar.FIELDNAME)
   ```

   // Note that month start with `0`, thus February is `1`.

If you simply want to compare the pure time, `which is before which` you can use:

2. `milliseconds` and simply compare those values with a < (less then)
3. Use the `Date` class and call `after()` or `before()`

If you store your values as milliseconds or `YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss` you can also add a `ORDER BY YOURTABLEROWWHICHINCLUDESTHEDATES ASC` to your `SQL`-query.